# How to convert NDWI into vector and export it?

Tags: google-earth-engine, normalized-difference-water-index

I am working over a collection to calculate NDWI. Now I want to convert each NDWI over the collection to vector and export it.
Following code is being used.

a function defined for masking

```
function maskLandsatclouds(image) {
var qa = image.select('BQA')
var cloudBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(4).int()
var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
 return image.updateMask(mask).select("B.*").copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"])
 }
```

filtering landsat data

```
var landsat8= ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA').filterBounds(geometry)
.filterDate('2016-07-01', '2020-10-22')
.sort('DATE_ACQUIRED')
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', 152))
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', 42))
.map(maskLandsatclouds)
```

defining threshold

```
 var waterThreshold = 0.1;
```

water extraction function:

```
var waterfunction = function(image){
  //add the NDWI band to the image
  var ndwi = image.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B5']).rename('NDWI');
  //get pixels above the threshold
  var water01 = ndwi.gt(waterThreshold);
  //mask those pixels from the image
  image = image.updateMask(water01).addBands(ndwi);

  var area = ee.Image.pixelArea();
  var waterArea = water01.multiply(area).rename('waterArea');

  image = image.addBands(waterArea);

  var stats = waterArea.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), 
    geometry: geometry, 
    scale: 30,
  });

  return image.set(stats);};
       var collection = landsat8.map(waterfunction);
      print(collection);

    var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
      imageCollection: collection.select('waterArea'), 
      region: geometry, 
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), 
      scale: 30,
    });

 var ndwiViz = {min: 0, max: 0.3, bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2']};


Map.addLayer(collection.median().clip(geometry),ndwiViz,"jj");
print(chart);
```